# Getting a user role from the user login name

Tags: user-roles

The question might be simple. Since I need to fix it soon I had to ask.

Currently I am modifying a free plugin. In that I am having the *user login* string.

How can I get the role for that login?

I'm using WordPress 3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `get_user_by()`, which will return a `WP_USER` object which contains roles and capabilities. More info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User).

```
$user = get_user_by( 'login', 'username');

$roles = $user->roles // this will contain an array of the roles the user is in
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`get_user_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) function.

**Example:**

Get all the roles assigned to the user `John Smith`, that uses the login `johnsmith`:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'login', 'johnsmith' );
print_r( $user->roles );
```

This might give you the following output:

```
Array ( [0] => author )
```

Comment: This is also fine. But not able to upvote because of my low points. Thank you..:)